# How to use a command from awk in the right way

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have the next command :

```
 awk -v M="$variable" -v B=$"version"-v R="Pass ok" -v K="1" 'BEGIN {FS=","; OFS=","} $1==M {$14=R} {$3=B} {$23=K} {print}' file1.csv > file2.csv
```

and i dont know why i get an output different than i wish, the parameter `(R="Pass ok")` the prints in several's lines of the file like the parameter `(K="1")`, please help me with this.

Notes :
I have this command in a script that i run of this way :
`./myscript.sh` variable

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

> i dont know why i get an output different than i wish

Because you wrote everything on a single line and you lost track of what pattern applies to what action.  Try this instead:

```
awk -v M="$variable" -v B="$version"-v R="Pass ok" -v K=1 '
        BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="," }
        $1 == M { $14 = R; $3 = B; $23 = K; print }
        $1 != M
    ' file1.csv > file2.csv
```

Comment: Hi, this is good, but in the "file2.csv" only have the line that awk modified, and all the infomation in the csv It is lost, do you have any idea ?

Comment: @shaveax: It was my understanding you want to do that.  If you also want to include the unchanged lines you can just add `$1 != M` at the end of the awk script (this will select and print the lines not matched by the `$1 == M` pattern).

Comment: ok, this is perfect for me, but i have a doubt related a script that i have, each time that iterate the script whit a while for example :

Comment: while read line
do
awk -v M="$variable" -v B=$"version"-v R="Pass ok" -v K=1 ' BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="," } $1 == M { $14 = R; $3 = B; $23 = K; print } ' file1.csv > file2.csv
done < list.csv

Comment: the result it put in the same line of the ($variable) that the while read for first time instead of the line where the ($variable) must be, for example in other line, I hope I explained well for this situation, thanks

Comment: @shaveax: Sorry, there was a typo in my script, it should have been `-v B="$version"` rather than `-v B=$"version"`.  I edited my answer (also to include the `$1 != M` pattern).

Comment: still yet after put in the right way this line (-v B="$version"), my file2.csv continues showing the error mentioned before.

Comment: @shaveax: Sorry, but my post above was meant to answer your initial question.  You're now changing your question to something unrelated, that I can't even parse.